# CSS background: transparent url() not displaying img

Tags: css, background-image

I'd like to replace the WooCommerce "Add to cart" button with a PNG image.

I'm using the following CSS in my child theme to do this:

```
.woocommerce .single_add_to_cart_button, .woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
  background: transparent url('http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/wp-content/themes/temper/images/buy.png') no-repeat !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  width: 109px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

I set opacity to 0 to get rid of the text "Add to Cart".

However, this only produces an element with a transparent background, and no background image:[image]

The button is directly to the right of the product quantity field: [example page](http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/product/dark-chocolate-coated-brazils/).

Why isn't the background image showing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your styles.css (line 151) you are setting opacity to 0:

```
.woocommerce .single_add_to_cart_button, 
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
   background: transparent url('http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/wp-content/themes/temper/images/buy.png') no-repeat !important;
   opacity: 0 !important;
   width: 109px;
   height: 46px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have opacity set to zero - so this is the reason why you cant see the image. Try to use

```
opacity: 1 !important;
```

Opacity documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 1):

Change the `opacity: 1 !important;` and to remove `Add to cart` text in button,remove text between `<button>` **Add To Cart** `</button>`.

Comment: I set opacity to 0 to get rid of the text "Add to Cart". I will have to find a way to get rid of the text.

Comment: I got rid of the "add to cart" text by using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-poor-guys-swiss-knife/)